# Why can't I add a single value to an entire column in PostgreSQL PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm new to PostgreSQL, so bear with me.

I have two tables, one called "polys" with several polygons and another called "box" that contains only one polygon (my bounding box).  My query selects all the polygons in "polys" that fall within the bounding box "box" - a clip if you will.  Both tables have two columns, one containing their ID's and another containing their GeoJSON called "the_geom".

What I want is one column containing IDs of polygons that fall within the bounding box, another column with these polygons' GeoJSONs called "the_geom_webmercator", another called "polygonarea" with each polygon's area, and then another column called "totalarea" which contains the SAME EXACT VALUE for each polygon (the value being the sum of all the polygons). However, simply asking for the SUM won't work since this returns only 1 value.  Instead, I want this value to fill the entire column.  Below is what I've tried; the `SUM...AS' is the portion in question.

```
SELECT polys.id, ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(polys.the_geom, box.the_geom),3857)
AS the_geom_webmercator,
ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(polys.the_geom,box.the_geom),3857))
AS polygonarea,
SUM(ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(polys.the_geom,box.the_geom),3857)))
AS totalarea FROM polys,box
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the SUM() aggregate-function you also need a GROUP BY statement.

I guess what you want is a WINDOW Function

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html

With window function you can calculate aggregates for single rows without GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
 polys.id, 
 ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(polys.the_geom, box.the_geom),3857) AS the_geom_webmercator,
 ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(polys.the_geom,box.the_geom),3857)) AS polygonarea,
 SUM(ST_Area(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(polys.the_geom,box.the_geom),3857)))  OVER () AS totalarea
FROM polys,box
```

Comment: Up and running with the suggested code.  Thank you very much.